# Missing sap.viz in PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, charts, sapui5

Good morning,

I am packaging a SAPUI5 application in PhoneGap. I added the resources folder of OpenUI5 in my android project but it does not contain sap.viz . The problem is that the application that i have to package in PhoneGap use charts from sap.viz so i need import that library in my project because the application will be offline so I should have that library in my local resources folder.

I was looking for but I didn't find anything....

Thanks a lot,

Borja.

Answer (score 2):

I hate to bring the bad news, but...

1. The sap.viz libraries are SAP proprietary, and as such not part of the OpenUI5 library. See https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/293eb945f0e945aaa776812481b4c533.html
2. In that same link, it mentioned:

> To include the SAPUI5 resources you need in your hybrid app, SAPUI5
>   mobile provides the following static mobile runtime packages:
>   sapui5-mobile-opt-static.zip or sapui5-mobile-static.zip. The packages
>   are not contained in the SAPUI5 runtime deployment. **The packages are
>   contained in the SCN download version of SAPUI5 and in the Open Source
>   version OpenUI5**

Now, on SCN no SAPUI5 is found to be downloaded. The only 'standalone' version of SAPUI5 is downloadable from the SAP Store at https://store.sap.com/sap/cp/ui/resources/store/html/SolutionDetails.html?pid=0000000352, but that contains the whoppingly old 1.16.3 version...

According to all the public documentation, this should be the only standalone, static SAPUI5 library available.
As I'm not an SAP customer, I honestly don't know if there are other ways to package a more current SAPUI5 library using Cordova. I would love to know some official statement from SAP regarding this.

Comment: Hi Qualiture,

I was reading about that... In my application I will need to do an initial download from back-end so, do you think could I download the sap.viz library from server? Maybe versions issues with libraries...

Comment: Hi Gargim, if you get that "pulling from the backend" realized, then please post your solution. I already tried that for the complete sap.ui.core libraries, didnt get it running.. Thanks zY